# Netbeans Create Standalone Jar

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an application with two libraries that are being used from the java\extensions folder. I would like this jar file be be runnable from any computer such as a computer without netbeans. What is the best way to create this jar? I have read some tutorials but they don't seem to answer my question.

Comment: Look at [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) or [OneJar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar). Or simply build the jar yourself using Ant or jar.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a standard NetBeans project with build.xml, I usually add a target like this to build.xml:

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <jar jarfile="${dist.jar}" update="true">
        <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" includes="**/*.class" />
        <zipfileset src="${libs.somelibrary.classpath}" includes="**/*.class"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Here somelibrary is a third party library that has been added to the project. Add a zipfileset element for each library you want to include in the jar file. You should already have something like this in project.properties for each of the libraries:

```
javac.classpath=\
    ${libs.somelibrary.classpath}:\
```

Comment: Should I add the above line or change it from the following?:     javac.classpath=\
    ${file.reference.RXTXcomm.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.guava.jar}

Comment: Don't edit project.properties, just add zipfileset elements to build.xml where you replace libs.somelibrary.classpath with file.reference.RXTXcomm.jar and file.reference.guava.jar.

Comment: Thank you! One more question. how  do I package the native library librxtxSerial.jnilib with the build?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used JNI libraries, so I don't know how to add that.